# How to add string to WPF DataBinding in ListView in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, string, wpf, listview, data-binding

I would like to add a string to my DataBinding with C# code behind and show them in a ListView column. For example I need to add "USD" string to the current_price binding and show in the ListView.

I have tried to solve the issue with string.Format(), but It did not suceed until now. I also tried string.Format("{0:C}", "current_price"), but it does not worked too.

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
listView_coins.View = gridView;
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "#",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("market_cap_rank")
});
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Name",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("name")
});
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Ticker",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("symbol")
});
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Change (24h)",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("price_change_percentage_24h")
});
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Price",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("{0} USD", "current_price"))
});

for (int i = 0; i < coinDatas.Count; i++)
{
    listView_coins.Items.Add(new CryptocurrencyDataModel
    {
        market_cap_rank = coinDatas[i].market_cap_rank,
        name = coinDatas[i].name,
        symbol = coinDatas[i].symbol.ToUpper(),
        price_change_percentage_24h = coinDatas[i].price_change_percentage_24h,
        current_price = coinDatas[i].current_price,
    });
}
```

I would like to get a result like 17.260 USD in the ListView column.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong constructor for your final `DisplayMemberBinding`.  The first argument to binding is the property path.  Giving it a formatted string is not going to work..  Better to create the binding using explicit, property -initialization syntax (e.g. `Source=`, `Path=`, etc.  That "{0} USD" part should be assigned to the Binding's `StringFormat` property

Comment: It would be great, but I would like to add more currencies to the binding like EUR or CAD. It based on a condition and that is why I should make them C# code behind.

Comment: I'm not telling you not to make them from code-behind.  I'm saying you are calling them with the wrong arguments

Comment: If you need different currencies, then why don't you have a currency column?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary not to set the path to the format string, but to set the value of the format string to the binding

```
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "Price",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(nameof(CryptocurrencyDataModel.current_price))
    {
        StringFormat="{0} USD"
    }
});
```

**P.S.** You can also set the monetary format of the output once in XAML, and adjust the display of the desired currency by changing the culture language of the UI element.